# Shape of current carrying loop in any arbitrary magnetic field

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, electric-current

Suppose we place a current carrying loop of wire in a magnetic field. Of, course its easy to see that for a uniform field the wire will experience uniform force in all directions and so it'll get stretched out into the shape of a circle. But I wanted to ask if we could make any comments about the shape of the wire, in any random magnetic field without knowing the exact function describing the field.

At places where the field is stronger, the wire will tend to get stretched out more so I suppose the local radius of curvature there would be less as compared to a point where the magnetic field strength is lower.

But thats just a qualitative rough way of looking at things. Is there some exact way to find out the answer to this